# How to alter the variables used in the derivation of the parameter used in the macro

Tags: parameters, macros, sas

Is there a general macro I can create that when given a parameter but not the equation it is derived from e.g. parameter = variable1 - variable2
Is it then possible to perform a function on these variable1 and variable2 without calling them in the macro and if so is there a general way to do this for any function.

I intend to use SAS but I am looking for a method so it doesn't have to be language specific

My current thought is something along the lines of 
%macro name(target_var = function(var1,...,varn);
I think the syntax is wrong but would it be possible to insert into the parameters of a macro the variable as a function?

Comment: That will probably depend on what language or application you are using the macro for.  Perhaps update the question to add a tag specifying the language you are interested in.

Comment: Should be possible in SAS. Please give an example of the macro you want to write.